# Контент вываливается из контейнера iframe в safari MacOS

Tags: html, css, отладка, iframe, safari

Встретил интересную проблему в браузере **safari** (*Version 13.0.5 (15608.5.11)*) на десктопе
(в других браузерах все работает без проблем)

Собрал пример проблемы на кодпене:
https://codepen.io/kudg0/pen/dyXpLpx

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/470109667?background=1&muted=1&autoplay=1"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Хост видео **vimeo**, и возможно проблема в инициализации видео контейнера на их стороне,
но все равно это очень странно и забавно

P.s: Решил проблему костылем, в браузере сафари поднимаю картинку вверх через transform, но это максимально тупо, поэтому хотелось бы найти решение)

[image: оранжевая граница, это тень у контейнера, по ней можно понять что контент вывалился]

Comment: Нашел траблу, решение ниже в комменте.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в object-fit, который был в css у **iframe**, если убрать его, то все становится в порядке.

```
iframe{
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Обновил свой [пример](https://codepen.io/kudg0/pen/dyXpLpx) на кодпене, там теперь есть решение проблемы и наглядное отображение ошибки.

P.s: ошибка ток в сафари